# Run a function if there is any change in the record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to create an encounter record from the request model. What I want is after_update :create_encounter to work only if there are any changes in the request record for which I was trying to create before_update :check_changes but I am not able to figure out how the check_changes function to be implemented to see if there are any changes in the request record. Please help

record.rb

```
class Request < ApplicationRecord
  after_create :create_encounter
  before_update :check_changes
  after_update :create_encounter

  has_many :encounters, dependent: :destroy

  def create_encounter
    hello = Encounter.new
    hello.request_id = self.id
    hello.status_change_date = DateTime.now.to_date
    hello.notes = self.notes
    hello.save
  end

 def check_changes

 end

end
```

schema for request

```
create_table "requests", force: :cascade do |t|

    t.string "applicant_name"
    t.string "pickup_location"
    t.string "notes"

end
```

Addition

```
def create_encounter
    if self.changed?
       hello = Encounter.new
       hello.request_id = self.id
       hello.status_change_date = DateTime.now.to_date
       hello.notes = self.notes
       hello.save
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`saved_changes?()`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Dirty.html#method-i-saved_changes-3F) from `ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Dirty` which will tell you whether the last call to `save` contained any changes.

Answer (score 1):

You must call the :create_encounter before_save.

Comment: any reason for that?

Comment: Because before the save it tells if there are any changes. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html

Comment: Please check the answer I posted. This is how it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Request < ApplicationRecord
  before_save :create_encounter
  after_create :create_encounters
  belongs_to :clinic
  belongs_to :client
  has_many :encounters, dependent: :destroy

  def create_encounter
    if self.changed?()
      hello = Encounter.new
      hello.request_id = self.id
      hello.admin_id = current_admin_id
      hello.status_change_date = DateTime.now.to_date
      hello.notes = self.notes
      hello.save
    end
  end

  def create_encounters
    hello = Encounter.new
    hello.request_id = self.id
    hello.admin_id = current_admin_id
    hello.status_change_date = DateTime.now.to_date
    hello.notes = self.notes
    hello.save
  end  

  def current_admin_id
    Admin.current_admin.try(:id)
  end

end
```

Comment: Then you should DRY it. Make one "def create_encounter" and use before_save :create_encounter if: ->(obj){ obj.changed? }